# KernelBB AdeHabitat package in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if anyone has used the `adehabitatHR` package in R and has tried to calculate a dynamic Brownian-Bridge model for an animal. I'm working through the vignette (`adeHabitat`, C. Calenge, 2015, page 108). The dataset is included with the package. The code is as follows:

```
data(puechcirc)
x <- puechcirc[1]
sig2 <- 58
liker(x, sig2 = 58, rangesig1 = c(1, 10))
tata <- kernelbb(x, sig1 = 6.23, sig2 = 58, grid = 50)
image(tata, addpoints=FALSE)
image(tata[[1]]$UD)
contour(getvolumeUD(tata)[[1]]$UD, level=95, add=TRUE, col="red", lwd=2)
```

My problem likes with the second to the last line (`image(tata[[1]]$UD`).  I keep getting the "`$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`" error. No matter what I try, I cannot coerce tata to a `data.frame`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
library(adehabitatHR)
data(puechcirc)
x <- puechcirc[1]
sig2 <- 58
liker(x, sig2 = 58, rangesig1 = c(1, 10))
tata <- kernelbb(x, sig1 = 6.23, sig2 = 58, grid = 50)
image(tata)
contour(getvolumeUD(tata), level=95, add=TRUE, lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. When you ran your edited code, did you not get a "no proper z matrix specific" error message after running the last line?

Comment: No, I did not. Everything runs smoothly.

Comment: Hmmmm ok. Thank you very much for your help!